# responsive sidebar wordpress theme

Tags: html, wordpress, css, sidebar, fluid-layout

I have the following and am wondering if anybody can help explain what I should to to make my sidebar in my markup collapse and drop below my main content in a wordpress blog theme. I have a feeling I may need a particular media@ query but am unsure of what.

This is all for a wordpress blog theme I am trying to establish from scratch. There is a header with a nav and image which I have no problem with, but, I need to have a main content container with a content div for articles floating left and sidebar div floating right for widgets.If anybody can help me kick off this process, I'd be eternally grateful.

CSS CODE:

```
.gridContainer {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 87.36%;
padding-left: 1.82%;
padding-right: 1.82%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

#LayoutDiv2 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

body, html {
height: 100%;
}

#content{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
width:80%;
}

#sidebar{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
width:20%;


}



/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
width: 90.675%;
padding-left: 1.1625%;
padding-right: 1.1625%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv2 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}



/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and     Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

.gridContainer {
width: 88.2%;
max-width: 1232px;
padding-left: 0.9%;
padding-right: 0.9%;
margin: auto;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv2 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<body>
<!--HEADER, CONTENT, FOOTER-->
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<!--HEADER--> 
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
        <!--NAVIGAIION + LOGO-->
        <nav>
            <div class="header">

                    <div id="logo"></div>   

                    <!--navigation list items-->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">work</a></li>

                    </ul>


            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--end of NAVIGATION + LOGO-->


  <div id="LayoutDiv2" class="clearfix">

        <div id="content">

            <p> This is the Content</p>     

        </div>


        <aside>

            <div id="sidebar">

                <p> This is the Sidebar</p>

            </div>

        </aside>





  </div><!--end of LayoutDiv2-->





</div><!--end of LayoutDiv1-->




</div><!--end of Grid Container, HEADER, CONTENT, FOOTER-->


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. However, now I have a further inquiry. I have content in the main content div, and widgets obviously in the sidebar such as a search form. The search form input and my text <p></p> content in the main div are escaping and overflowing out of their respective divs. When I add padding, the divs also collapse with content div above sidebar div. What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for your content and your sidebar for example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #sidebar{ clear: both; width: 100%; }
    #content{ clear: both; width: 100%; }
}
```

This allows you to place the divs underneath each other and make them the full width of the page.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49f7X/) for an working example.